# Electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay() method incorrect [OSX]

Tags: electron

Im currently using a 2021 Macbook pro which has the screen resolution of 3456x2234.

When i run the following command:

```js
Electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay()}
```

I get the following response:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "bounds": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 2056,
        "height": 1329
    },
    "workArea": {
        "x": 34,
        "y": 44,
        "width": 2022,
        "height": 1285
    },
    "accelerometerSupport": "unknown",
    "monochrome": false,
    "colorDepth": 30,
    "colorSpace": "{primaries:BT709, transfer:IEC61966_2_1_HDR, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}",
    "depthPerComponent": 10,
    "size": {
        "width": 2056,
        "height": 1329
    },
    "displayFrequency": 120,
    "workAreaSize": {
        "width": 2022,
        "height": 1285
    },
    "scaleFactor": 2,
    "rotation": 0,
    "internal": true,
    "touchSupport": "unknown"
}
```

Im expecting the size.width and size.height to match 3456x2234 however they don't. Whats happening here and how can i get the correct screen resolution on OSX?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles here i worked out i had the display set as 'scaled - more space'. If i change display to be 'default' the reported values are as expected (times by scaleFactor) to get the real display resolution.